# Fetch issues in backbone collection with id

Tags: javascript, jquery, backbone.js, underscore.js, handlebars.js

Following is my JSON:

```
[ 
{  
    "id" : "1",
    "type" : "report"
},
{  
    "id" : "2",
    "type" : "report"
},
{  
    "id" : "1",
    "type" : "email"
},
]
```

Consider, json is returned from backbone collection -> service call.
Now, when I'm using the json response to render my html table using backbone view and handlebars template system.
2 rows gets displayed, instead there should be 3 rows.

Note:
collection Parse response is returning correct json (i.e. 3 rows).
When I overwrite the `id` using collection parse with unique random generated number all 3 rows get displayed.
This is not ok, because I don't want to change the `id`.

I want the row to be displayed as following:

```
1 reports
2 reports
1 email
```

Comment: try changing the idAttribute [hint here: backbone api](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the documentation for [Collection add](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-add),

> Note that adding the same model (a model with the same id) to a
>   collection more than once is a no-op.

While I cannot see a reason for why two different objects should have the same id, you may have a valid reason. One suggestion would be to add another property to each object in the json response, `_dummyId` and set that to an autoincrementing value from the server side. On the client side, in your model definition code, you then set the `idAttribute` to `_dummyId`.

JSON response,

```
[ 
{  
    "id" : "1",
    "_dummyId": "1",
    "type" : "report"
},
{  
    "id" : "2",
    "_dummyId": "2",
    "type" : "report"
},
{  
    "id" : "1",
    "_dummyId": "3",
    "type" : "email"
},
]
```

Your model definition, [from http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute](http://backbonejs.org/#Model-idAttribute),

```
var Meal = Backbone.Model.extend({
  idAttribute: "_dummyId"
});
```

That said, I do hope there is an elegant setting in backbone, something that makes a backbone collection acts a list instead of a set.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to solve this, you have to set new unique id for each model you add to collection.
Try this method:

```
initialize: function() {
      this.set("id", this.generateID());
},
generateID = function () {
    return 'xxxxxxxx-xxxx-4xxx-yxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx'.replace(/[xy]/g, function (c) {
        var r = Math.random() * 16 | 0, v = c == 'x' ? r : (r & 0x3 | 0x8);
        return v.toString(16);
    });
}
```

If you need the original id, you need to save it before, and after create the new one, you set the original in another model attribute.
Backbone ignore me when I did @amith-george solution setting `idAttribute` to another `dummyId`